# Find the instance that has highest a certain attribute

Tags: python, oop

This is a car class.

I want to find the car with the most `cc` and what its `brand` is.

```
  class car:

    category = 'auto'

    def __init__(self,brand,color,cc):
        self.brand = brand
        self.color = color
        self.cc = cc

def fastest(*args):
        return max(args)



nissanCar = car("Nissan","red",1800)
MercendesCar = car("Mercendes","gold",1600)
LamborghiniCar = car("Lamborghini","green",3000)

print(f"The fastest car is {fastest(nissanCar.cc,MercendesCar.cc,LamborghiniCar.cc)} cc and the its brand is ")
```

This returns:

```
The fastest car is 3000 cc and its brand is
```

How to know what the brand of that car is?

Comment: so many downvotes to a new user and no explanation for that at all.

Comment: I suspect the downvotes are because this looks like a homework problem and you haven't followed the guidance on homework here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: They could have asked before jumping into conclusions. This is based on a  beginners tutorial on the internet that I decided to do a trickier version of it for practice. I have provided my reproducible example and I have solved half of it apparently. I am asking for the other part here. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: I see you've accepted an answer, but I've left you another one which uses the oop features of Python to save you writing your own function. Maybe study both as they are useful examples of two ways to approach the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated your code so that it can display multiple fastest cars. There might be in the end tons of cars and there could be more than one that have the same cc.

If you have any questions let me know in comments.

Welcome to Stack overflow!

```
class car:

    category = 'auto'

    def __init__(self,brand,color,cc):
        self.brand = brand
        self.color = color
        self.cc = cc

def fastest(cars):
        max_cc = max([car.cc for car in cars])
        fastest_cars = [car for car in cars if car.cc == max_cc]
        return fastest_cars



NissanCar = car("Nissan","red",1800)
MercedesCar = car("Mercendes","gold",1600)
LamborghiniCar = car("Lamborghini","green",3000)

fastest_cars = fastest([NissanCar, MercedesCar, LamborghiniCar])
for fastest_car in fastest_cars:
    print(f"The fastest car is {fastest_car.brand} with {fastest_car.cc} cc")
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently your 'fastest' function just wraps the built-in 'max' function. This isn't very useful as it actually makes the code less readable and just looking at the name you'd think it does something more specific. If you just want to return the highest cc you could just call max directly.

However, this still leaves you with your issue. By just finding the max `cc` you have lost the association of that `cc` value with a specific instance of the `car` class. Probably the best solution here is to modify the car class so that you can sort the class objects directly.

```
class car:
    category = 'auto'

    def __init__(self, brand, color, cc):
        self.brand = brand
        self.color = color
        self.cc = cc

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.cc < other.cc


NissanCar = car("Nissan","red",1800)
MercedesCar = car("Mercendes","gold",1600)
LamborghiniCar = car("Lamborghini","green",3000)

fastest_car = max([NissanCar, MercedesCar, LamborghiniCar])

print(fastest_car.brand, fastest_car.cc)
```

Comment: I tried to replace your line with this: `car_list = [nissanCar,MercedesCar,LamborghiniCar]` but it gives : `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'car' and 'car'`

Comment: Did you use my code for the car class? Adding the __lt__ method should make this work, I've edited my code so it uses your cars.

Comment: Yes. I saw it, I just don't understand why it did not work previously. I had only changed the `car_list` line. Please tell me also what's the point of the __lt__ method and how it works.

Comment: The lt method stands for 'less than'. It defines how Python decides if one car is 'less than' another car. In this case I've specified that the cc of the car should be used. If this method is defined then you can use inequalities, max, min and sort on the class. If it isn't, you will see the error that you posted above.

Comment: I had used it in the example above and go t the error. I only changed the `car_list` line.`class car:
    category = 'auto'

    def __init__(self, brand, color, cc):
        self.brand = brand
        self.color = color
        self.cc = cc

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.cc < other.cc

car_list = [nissanCar,MercedesCar,LamborghiniCar]

print(max(car_list).brand)`